# How to determine the type of finish used on a piece of furniture?

Tags: sealing, wooden-furniture, polyurethane

I have a table that I want to add another clear-coat layer to (to smooth and level without sanding). It's already stained and sealed, so I want to choose a clear-coat (polyurethane, lacquer, epoxy) that will bind with what was used on it before, but I don't know what was used before.

What's the best way to determine what kind of finish is on this table, so that additional coats will stick properly?

Comment: FYI, the coating on furniture isn't usually called "sealant". "Varnish" or simply the "finish" are more common.

Comment: The instructions on most finishes normally call for a scuff sanding before an additional coat, so I don't think you're going to get away without sanding completely.